# Wait for the execution of a queue with queuejs

Tags: javascript, queue, settimeout

I need to easy chain some functions with Javascript. I have found some libraries and the smarter one seems to be queryjs.

But I need to wait for the execution of each function waiting for the end of the the previous one. I've tried to make the trick using `setTimeout`, but is not working at all, everything is executed at the same time. Code is like this:

```
<script src="http://d3js.org/queue.v1.min.js"></script>

<script>
    function timingOut(i){
        console.log('timing out: '+i);
    }

    function timingOut2(i){ 
        console.log('foo 2: '+i);
    }

    var foo = function(i,callback){
        callback(null,i);
    }

    var foo2 = function(i,callback){
        setTimeout(timingOut2(i),5000);
        callback(null,i);
    }
    var finish = function(error,results){
        console.log(results);
    }

    queue(2)
        .defer(foo,1)
        .defer(foo2,2)
        .awaitAll(finish);
    </script>
```

I'm not using other solutions such as jquery animate because not all functions will be animations.

Comment: JavaScript has just one single thread, so in the end everything is executed sequentially (except Worker and AJAX)!

Comment: thanks, problem with workers is that I can't manipulate DOM. Thanks to `setTimeout` function is possible to emulate the behavour I want to have but the idea is to try to avoid nesting infinite `setTimeout` functions